# Returning Max value in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am using the code below to return a Max value

```
SELECT t2.QUOTEID, t2.SALES_REF, Max(t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL) AS MaxOfOBJECTION_LEVEL, t1.OBJECTION_CALL_DATE
FROM TBLOBJECTIONSNEW AS t1 RIGHT JOIN TBLQUOTESNEW AS t2 ON t1.QUOTE_ID = t2.QUOTEID
GROUP BY t2.QUOTEID, t2.SALES_REF, t1.OBJECTION_CALL_DATE
HAVING (((Max(t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL)) Is Not Null));
```

However, when I run this code, 3 records are returned as there are 3 different OBJECTION_CALL_DATE's

How can I return just one record - the maximum of t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL?

Comment: Don't really understand your question. If you only want the max of t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL, then why do you group by and return t1.OBJECTION_CALL_DATE?

Comment: I dont't only want the max of t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL. I want the max of t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL and it's corresponding OBJECTION_CALL_DATE

Comment: Well, that's exactly what you get as you write: when I run this code, 3 records are returned as there are 3 different OBJECTION_CALL_DATE's.

Comment: But I want only one record the one with the max of t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve this myself :-

```
SELECT t2.QUOTEID, t2.SALES_REF, t1.OBJECTION_LEVEL, t1.OBJECTION_CALL_DATE
FROM TBLOBJECTIONSNEW as t1 RIGHT JOIN TBLQUOTESNEW as t2 ON t1.QUOTE_ID = t2.QUOTEID
WHERE (((t1.[OBJECTION_LEVEL])=(SELECT MAX(OBJECTION_LEVEL) FROM TBLOBJECTIONSNEW t3 where t1.QUOTE_ID = t3.QUOTE_ID)))
```